# Find all paths in a directed, unweighted graph for a selected node

Tags: javascript, graph, nodes

There have been a few similar questions around this topic but I am having trouble finding something that matches my requirements. I am working on a food web program (in Javascript) and am interested in finding all the possible food chains (paths) that involve a selected species (node). In other words, when someone selects a species in the graph, I want to list or highlight each of the individual food chains that involve the selected species. See an [EOL Food Web](http://education.eol.org/eco/ecovis.php?ecosystem=122%20'EOL%20Food%20Web') for an example of the type of graph I am working on.

I'm hoping this shouldn't be too complicated because the edges are unweighted (have no value) but do have a direction. I don't need shortest or longest path - just all possible variations involving the species in question.

I was thinking that a clever solution might involve finding all the "down" (towards prey) paths from the selected node first and then do the same for "up" (towards predators) paths. Then just concatenate the downs and ups for all possible combinations. But that likely isn't very elegant.

Many thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is roughly correct.

- Recursively traverse the graph "downwards" recording all paths.
- Recursively traverse the graph "upwards" recording all paths.
- Produce all path combinations from the previous two sets.

This assumes that the graph has no cycles (i.e. no creature feeds on itself or on any of its predators or predators of predators, etc.)

Here is some pseudocode for traversal. Starting at the node of interest using a recursive approach:

```
paths := []
for all children
    extendPath(paths, child)


function extendPath(NodeList[] paths, Node node)    
    for path in paths
        path.add(node)

    for child in node.children
        extendPath(paths, child)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply - good to know that at least someone else agrees with my approach! I'm using vis.js on my new version (was formally using d3) as the graphing engine and so have access to a couple of objects (nodes and edges) that contain all the information that I should need. However, I'm struggling with the traversing code. Do you (or anyone else) have some thoughts on what that might look like?

Comment: Here is some pseudocode for traversal. Starting at the node of interest using a recursive approach:

paths := []
for all children
    extendPath(paths, child)
    
    
function extendPath(NodeList[] paths, Node node)    
    for path in paths
        path.add(node)
        
    for child in node.children
        extendPath(paths, child)

I added the code to the answer since I cannot format the comment. Please mark the answer as accepted.